# Excel filter times range items in column and sum values

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Example

```
time     Type  Total      
8:00:00  B       2
8:03:00  S       3
8:07:00  S       10
8:10:00  B       5
8:17:00  B       7  
8:21:00  S       8
8:28:00  B       12
```

Result
Each 15min

```
8:00-8:15    B=7  S=13    
8:15-8:30    B=19 S=8
```

Comment: Maybe this statement could be reworded into some sort of question? :)

Answer (score 1):

If the Example table you give is placed at A1, then you can create rows like this:

```
8:00:00    8:15:00   B=    =SUMIFS(C2:C8,A2:A8,">="&F2,A2:A8,"<"&G2,B2:B8,"B")    S=    =SUMIFS(C2:C8,A2:A8,">="&F2,A2:A8,"<"&G2,B2:B8,"S")
```

Output:

> 8:00:00   8:15:00 B=  7   S=  13

There are many other ways of accomplishing this, but this is quick and easy, just put in the next row in the time columns

```
 =F2+TIME(0,15,0)    =G2+TIME(0,15,0)
```

then drag down as far as you want (where F2 & G2 hold your first time values).

Comment: +1 Works just as well, also, I come across `time()` for the first time!

Answer (score 1):

You mean how to this?

Do you have the intervals already? If so, you could use `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$B$2:$B$8,B$10,$A$2:$A$8,">="&LEFT($A11,FIND("-",$A11)),$A$2:$A$8,"<"&MID($A11,FIND("-",$A11)+1,99))
```

It's a bit long but if you have the time intervals in the format `hh:mm` instead of either `h:mm` or `hh:mm`, you can shorten it to:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$B$2:$B$8,B$10,$A$2:$A$8,">="&LEFT($A11,5),$A$2:$A$8,"<"&RIGHT($A11,5))
```

The thing with the first formula is that it doesn't matter whether your range is listed as `08:00-08:15` or `08:00:00-08:15:00` or `9:45-10:00`, it will take the right times. Also, you can type the formula once, and drag it left and right, up and down for the format of the table, see a screenshot:

[image]

I put one formula in cell B11 and dragged it to the other cells.